# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SOME TYPE', small confusion when passing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, types

Below is how I am using my reusable component `Badge` made by me. It has types of props as follows but this gives some kind of error as:

[image]

Here is full code,

```js
const variantsMap = {
  done: "success",
  processing: "info",
  suspened: "warning",
  cancelled: "error",
};

interface ITransactionProps {
  status: "done" | "processing" | "suspened" | "cancelled";
  label: string;
}

const MyComponent = ({ status, label }: ITransactionProps) => {
  return <Badge variant={variantsMap[status]}>{label}</Badge>;
};

interface IBadgeProps {
  variant: "success" | "info" | "warning" | "error";
  children: string;
}

const Badge = ({ variant, children }: IBadgeProps) => {
  return <div className={`badge bordered circular ${variant}`}>{children}</div>;
};
```

How can this be solved in proper way? I would like to know all the ways if we can solve it in multiple ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `variantsMap` a bit differently

```
const variantsMap: Record<string, "success" | "info" | "warning" | "error"> = ...
```

I would extract that into a new type for readability.

```
type Variant = "success" | "info" | "warning" | "error";

const variantsMap: Record<string, Variant> = ...

interface IBadgeProps {
  variant: Variant;
  children: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice simple and clean solution is to use `as const`:

```
const variantsMap = {
  done: "success",
  processing: "info",
  suspened: "warning",
  cancelled: "error",
} as const;
```

Now `variantsMap` is typed as:

```
{
    readonly done: "success";
    // ...
}
```

which means accessing properties results in literal types, not `string` which was the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgDUUpgUA7eAXjgCIATCGyQ84AH15gcaJAGcZwNgHMR4njICuMukL4readtIA2RpLork0gmfABuzVhxkBZFGABciJFah8APEws7DAANHA2LEoAfHDcAN7kcHACQp5q6mjScjwhiXCSEFnySmkKmBA5eRpaSDppAO7MbArKuUkGbMamfGlIUDhQlQC%20FgowfZjo9ACSACpQ7DLoMMCCAAo4YDJwCUk2KDCanoGOMBRJRigARkhGnhEtFEOUVmw2cM7UAMK4kEIcsTgAAo4uEYAdNGFLjcjHAhp45gs3stVmwNhAtgBKWIxXZwIiHKBsOB%20ABCKD4ino9iCHE4cRppxcbgA2vtDjIALpDKJxaG3IZ%20AD05MpSCiT1GHAmUzg01FVPRWx2eUZwXuMEiinOcDQAAtgEY%20EQ2J4AFIAZQAGgA6ACiphAtXg4geSieL2s8AV9G4ILgao4YX1huNtThCJ9Spk2M4uLyBPURJJfGAtl1lzkADkUE76QADK4UqlwK7QPh9My64BQNDqS5QOAAEgZDmCQ3zPLiIaNJsFQtTtgl5BG5CAA)

The full code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

type Variant = "done" | "processing" | "suspened" | "cancelled";

const variantsMap: Record<Variant, string> = {
  done: "success",
  processing: "info",
  suspened: "warning",
  cancelled: "error",
};

interface ITransactionProps {
  status: Variant;
  label: string;
}

const MyComponent = ({ status, label }: ITransactionProps) => {
  return <Badge variant={variantsMap[status]}>{label}</Badge>;
};

interface IBadgeProps {
  variant: string;
  children: JSX.Element | string;
}

const Badge = ({ variant, children }: IBadgeProps) => {
  return <div className={`badge bordered circular ${variant}`}>{children}</div>;
};
```

Comment: this way `variant` prop of `Badge` will be just the string not the actual `variant` that i wanted to have